# Код не удаляет символ из первого элемента списка

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
i=int(0)

f=open('locallist.txt','r')
program_list=f.readlines()
for line in range(len(program_list)):
    program_list[i].replace("\n", "")
    i=i+1
    print(line)
    print(program_list)
f.close()
```

Выводит: `['Visual Studio Code\n', 'Mozila']`
UPD: Удаляет только из последнего элемента
Как исправить это недорозумение - не понимаю.

Comment: Скорее всего в конце файла просто нет перевода строки, ничего не удаляет в общем )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Строки это иммутабельный тип. А все строковые методы возвращают новую строку.

```py
program_list[i] = program_list[i].replace("\n", "")
```